# How long is a 'day' at Roland Garros (French Open) tennis?

Tags: paris, sports-events

If I was to buy a day ticket at the French Open, what time could I arrive? And what time would I have to leave?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I'm unsure as to whether this question fits within the scope of Travel. It seems to me that the travel reason behind it is very faint. FYI: [check the programme for opening times](https://tickets.rolandgarros.com/programme)

Comment: You could also try the sports site for questions like this http://sports.stackexchange.com (p.s. events and days out are off topic now?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The games are usually starting around 11 AM and ending up when they are concluded or worse case when the sun sets!

I have finally found the official schedule here :
https://tickets.rolandgarros.com/en/schedule